# Searching for 'stackoverflow' in Google shows cookies policy instead of meta description

Tags: bug, status-completed, google

When I search for 'stackoverflow' in Google, it displays Stack Overflow's cookies policy instead of the meta description. Like:

[image]

Is it a bug?

Just to clarify I am from the EU, so I need to accept cookies.

Comment: People in the US have to accept cookies too

Comment: We have had this before IIRC and was resolved by moving the div with that consent to a different location in the page. Maybe something was refactored that caused this regression. It is the first div in the page directly following the `<header>` tag.

Comment: Actually, I am facing a similar problem for a site of mine. So I saw the opportunity here that somebody of you is going to fix this anyway and maybe the answer could be helpful for my case (and maybe others too). I do not want to be impolite, but maybe the guy fixing this could give a bit more detailed answer on how to avoid this in general. Or do i have to post this in the regular forum too?

Comment: Well, if you're lucky the dev who fixes this will provide some details but for this case you can easily do the detective work yourself: grab the source of the SO html page while not logged in, store it on disk for later reference. Find the text you see in Google in the html you just saved, notice where it is in relation to other elements. Wait for the fix to be build out, repeat the process, diff the two results.

Comment: I'll gamble for now, but if there is no fix till tomorrow, ill go detective conan.

Comment: Pfft. Who uses Google anyway

Comment: @SombreroChicken That's it, I'm switching back to [Yahoo! Search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1x6L.png).

Comment: Internet before GDPR: 50% porn, 40% cat memes, 10% other stuff. Internet after GDPR: 30% porn, 20% cat memes, 50% cookie dialog boxes.

Comment: @czorp I imagine that asking about your site would be on topic at [Webmasters.SE], as this is in a similar vein to SEO (in my opinion, at least). Do check their policies and for duplicates before asking, though.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's not a bug, per se. The text in question is the first significant text you come to on the page (below the header, which has no real text to speak of), in terms of the order of HTML

[image: Cookie text]

They have a valid meta description tag.

```
<meta name="description" content="Stack Overflow is the largest, most trusted online community for developers to learn, share​ ​their programming ​knowledge, and build their careers.">
```

Google, somehow, thinks that cookie text is more relevant. It's not really fixable by Stack Overflow directly. As noted [elsewhere](https://moz.com/blog/why-wont-google-use-my-meta-description), they could always add the `nosnippet` tag

```
<meta name="robots" content="nosnippet">
```

but that might be worse, not better. I'd just leave it be if I were them. If you're searching for "Stack Overflow", which shows the site index page, that does a good job of explaining what SO does. My bet is few people find the home page by searching anyways, compared to searching for specific problems.

Comment: They could easily move that div towards the bottom of the HTML though. Google thinks it's significant *because* it's at the top

Comment: I thought no search engines paid attention to meta tags, because of their misuse.

Comment: @Raedwald meta descriptions are still valid, because you can tell search engines what *you* think the page is about. It's up to them to decide if they agree. You might be thinking of meta keywords, which was almost always misused and is generally ignored by engines.

Comment: @andrewtweber I'm not sure moving it would help all that much. It's one of the few static pieces of text on the front page. The rest is a rotating list of questions

Answer (score 7):

Google search results now shows the proper text

> [image]